# Ruby Bundler Permission issue

Tags: ruby, permissions, rubygems, bundler

So, I'm positive I once did a `sudo bundle install` out of desperation, which I now understand is a no-no.  But now, when i try to run `bundle install`, I get the following error:

```
Installing culerity (0.2.12) /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:294:in `generate_bin': You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bin directory. (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:196:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/source.rb:100:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:217:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0.rc.6/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

I've tried removeing everything in ~/.bundle ~/.gem .bundle Gemfile.lock as well as any reference to culerity or capybara in /Library/Ruby (OSX 10.6).  I also checked to make sure permissions were set correctly (not root) on all my files in this project. I also cleared the gem cache.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0.rc2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
#gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri', '1.4.1'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for certain environments:
# gem 'rspec', :group => :test
# group :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end

gem 'haml', '3.0.15'
gem 'mogli', '0.0.13' #, :path => "~/Sites/mogli"
gem 'facebooker2', '0.0.4'
gem 'geokit'
gem 'acts_as_restful_list'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", '2.0.0.beta.19'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara', '0.3.9'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '0.3.2'
  gem 'cucumber', '0.8.5'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'launchy'    # So you can do Then show me the page
end
```

Also, I have rvm on my system, but I'm using the system ruby for this project.

Any ideas on what's causing the permission issue?  Surely, I'm not stuck using `sudo bundle install`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It look like you are using the system's ruby. You have a few options:

- use sudo to install your bundle system wide. it could be a problem with conflicting gems from different applications.
- use bundle install --path bundle_dir, which is going to install the gems in bundle_dir
- use rvm (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com), this program will allow you to use different ruby versions, and different gem sets.

Answer (score -1):

Try to touch a file in the particular path. I guess OS X is protecting these directories a bit more than just the normal way? I think OS X supports ACL's with their filesystem, maybe you have to look there?

Answer (score -4):

maybe try using chmod on everything, but looks like you'll need to run it as sudo...not sure why that's not an option...

Comment: This is a very bad suggestion.  Going and chmodding all your system directories is a bad idea, there are reasons you need to use sudo to access them.